# ¿Se puede mostrar un resultado generado en PHP en un HTML?

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo un programa que hace varios cálculos y al final genera el resultado en un `$resultado`, los datos se ingresan desde el HTML en `<form method="POST" action="archivo.php" >`

Por ejemplo en el `<form>`, el usuario ingresa:

Valor 1 + Valor 2

Se envían a archivo.php por medio de un Botón para sumarse y el resultado sale en `$resultado`

Y lo que quiero es que en la pagina en HTML (aunque se tenga que recargar la pagina) muestre Algo como:

"Tu valor es igual a 5"

Donde 5 es lo que quedo en `$resultado`.

Lo que quería saber es si se puede y de ser así como mostrar el resultado en el HTML o si es mas conveniente hacerlo todo en un PHP.

Comment: PHP es un preprocesador de hipertexto, HTML es básicamente hipertexto. Ahora creo que es un poco confusa tu pregunta, pero creo a que te refieres a interactuar con PHP sin recargar  tu página, si es así quizás te interese preguntar sobre AJAX.

Comment: Hola @NekoOs no es necesario que no se recargue, he editado la pregunta para que sea un poco mas especifica con lo que necesito. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

**archivo.html:**

```html
<form method="post" action="archivo.php">
    <input name="valor1">
    <input name="valor2">
</form>
```

**archivo.php:**

Si solo quieres imprimirle:

```
<?php
    $valor1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'valor1');
    $valor2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'valor2');
    $resultado = $valor1 + $valor2;
    echo "Tu valor es igual a $resultado";
```

Si quieres replicar el formulario inicial, para hacer un nuevo calculo quizás:

```php
<?php
    $valor1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'valor1');
    $valor2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'valor2');
    $resultado = $valor1 + $valor2;
?>

<form method="post" action="archivo.php">
    <input name="<?php echo $valor1 ?>">
    <input name="<?php echo $valor2 ?>">
    <span><?php echo "Tu valor es igual a $resultado"; ?>
</form>
```

Recuerda que puedes mezclar código PHP en contenido HTML, como lo expresa  php.net:

> las páginas de PHP contienen HTML con código incrustado que hace "algo"

Te dejo el enlace para que leas el contenido completo: http://php.net/manual/es/intro-whatis.php

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede lo que comentas lo que tienes que hacer es que tu archivo en lugar de guardarlo como `.hmtl` lo guardes como `.php`.

Luego en archivo.php poner algo como lo que sigue:

```
<?php
    $valor1 = $_POST["valor1"];
    $valor2 = $_POST["valor2"];
    $resultado = $valor1 + $valor2;
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>El resultado es <?php echo $resultado ?>.</p>

</body>
</html>
```